# Is it recommended to accept an uncited plagiarised answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

One of my questions got answers from a user. The user had provided the exact answer to my question.

So, in general, I need to upvote because of clarity and explanation and accept because it is answering the question.

But, what should I do if I find that the answer is partially or fully plagiarised from some source and the source is uncited in the answer apart from commenting?

Options available to me:

1. Upvote and accept
2. Upvote but not accept
3. Accept but not upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the answer contains plagiarised content, it should be deleted, because it can be a [copyright infringement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement). So, you should vote to delete it or flag it for a moderator to intervene. You should not upvote or accept it, because that may encourage the plagiarist to provide more plagiarised answers without people realizing it. Actually, I would say that you should downvote it to discourage the plagiarist.

**We want to be a site of high-quality original answers/questions.**

I would expect other sites to do the same, but, unfortunately, other sites don't care too much about this and let their users copy (e.g. once one of my questions was copied from someone on Quora and posted there too).

[Our content](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) is licensed under [Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-SA 4.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), which basically means that you can copy and share, but you need to give proper attribution and you must license your content that is based on ours under the same license, but there are other restrictions...

So, in short, in case an answer is (even just partially) plagiarised and there's no evidence of giving proper attribution

1. downvote,
2. don't accept, and
3. flag for the deletion or moderator intervention (so that they can delete the answer)

Even if that answer answers your question. You may consider provide an answer to your own question **with your own words**, in that case, once you know the answer (because that other plagiarised answer will most likely be deleted).